# Flutter flutter/CMakeLists.txt "#" This character is not allowed

Tags: flutter, cmake

CMake Error at flutter/CMakeLists.txt:85 (add_custom_command):   add_custom_command called with OUTPUT containing a "#".  This character is not allowed.

Launching lib\main.dart on Windows in debug mode...
lib\main.dart:1
CMake Error at flutter/CMakeLists.txt:85 (add_custom_command): add_custom_command called with OUTPUT containing a "#".  This character is not allowed.
Exception: Unable to generate build files
Exited (sigterm)

Comment: From which repo have you downloaded the sources of flutter?

Comment: Flutter dev repo

Comment: Do you mean https://github.com/flutter/flutter? But it doesn't contain `CMakeLists.txt`. Please, describe (in the question post) **exact steps** which cause given error.

Comment: Launching lib\main.dart on Windows in debug mode...
lib\main.dart:1
CMake Error at flutter/CMakeLists.txt:85 (add_custom_command):
  add_custom_command called with OUTPUT containing a "#".  This character is not allowed.


Exception: Unable to generate build files
Exited (sigterm)

Comment: Your directory's full path might contain a "#" which is discouraged.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in comments by @Ṃųỻịgǻňạcểơửṩ, make sure that there's no `#` character in any of the directories in your path to where the Flutter project is located. For example if you have path like this;

`C:\\projects\ui#\your_project`

then you will get the error like the one you described. In this case you have to change the name of the direcory `ui#` to something that does not contain the `#` character, e.g., `ui`, so that the path become

`C:\\projects\ui\your_project`